# Test for XML declaration and add if it's missing

Tags: unix, xml

I have a program which expects input XML files having an XML declaration of the form `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` (all our files are UTF-8, it really has to be that string).

Some of my input files are missing the XML declaration.

What's the best way to test a file to see if it begins with that XML declaration, and prepend it if it's missing?  Is there a command for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xmllint did the job!

```
$ cat foo.xml
<A>B</A>
$ xmllint foo.xml --encode UTF-8
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<A>B</A>
$
```